# git merge not creating merge commit, no MERGE_HEAD

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

Using Git 1.8.1.2 on Linux, I have been working on two different branches based on `master` in parallel (call them A and B), and also created a third branch (call it M) which merges those two branches—so far with no non-merge commits of its own.

After doing some work on one of the “primary” branches (A), I checked out the merge branch (`git checkout M`), verified that it already had everything in B (`git merge B` reports `Already up-to-date.`) , and so I `git merge A` to pull in the new work on A.

Some merge conflicts are reported, which is expected. I edit the affected files to remove the conflict markers, then `git add` them. All looking normal so far.

But then when I `git commit`, the commit message gives no indication of this being a merge. If I proceed, the resulting commit (in the M branch) looks like just a simple commit (atop my prior merge of A and B); `git show` does not report `Merge:` parents. Prior to the commit, `.git` contains `MERGE_MODE` (empty) but there is no `MERGE_HEAD`.

I am not using any special merge strategy, so I suppose the default (`recursive`) is being used. Anyway this does not look like a strategy problem: the contents of the working tree appear exactly like I would expect them to.

If I manually create `MERGE_HEAD` with the hash of the head of A before committing, the resulting commit looks normal e.g. in `gitg`, though of course this makes me a little nervous.

What could be going on? Is this a bug in Git—is there ever any reason for `MERGE_HEAD` not be created after `git merge` command which did not create a commit? 1.8.4.3 appears to have the same behavior.

Comment: (Any particular reason this got two downvotes?)

Comment: We had the same problem today, but didn't manage to pin down the problem. It worked flawlessly on other machine though. I don't understand those downvotes.

Comment: I have the same problem. Doing the same merge on someone elses computer works fine, which makes this behavior even stranger. I write my commit messages with gedit, mergetool is meld, IDE is netbeans and the repo is on a btrfs partition. Any comon point with you by any chance?

Comment: Doing the same operation with the IDE closed is fine. Does it also work for you?

Comment: I also use NetBeans. I do not remember now if the IDE was open at the time; typically I use the IDE to make simple commits during development, and a shell to do all other Git operations (including merge commits). Possible it is somehow looking at my working copy in a background thread and somehow mangling it.

Comment: Found it thanks to the hint from @fred-b: [NetBeans bug #242625](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=242625)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should use

```
git merge --no-ff your_feature_branch
```

Comment: Thanks, but the documentation for this option (_Create a merge commit even when the merge resolves as a fast-forward_) would not seem to apply here, since the merge did _not_ resolve as a fast-forward.