# Git Merging not showing server side code

Tags: android, git

I am on android studio.

I have 2 branches: one is the `animation` branch and the second is `develop` branch. `Develop` branch created from the origin, and the `animation` branch from another branch.

I want to merge these two branches but the issue is that whenever I hit merge on android studio with the conflicted files, the server side code is just an empty fully.
I never run into such issue and I have restarted the android studio, cleared caches but nothing helping.

Can someone please explain me what is going on?
Important to mention that whenever I pull the `develop` or `animation` view the code is OK.

Comment: anyone please?help?

Comment: Can you try from the command line? `git checkout oneBranch; git merge theOtherBranch`.

Comment: ok let me try that one too

Comment: hmmm here is what i get

Comment: Removing app/src/main/res/values-v19/styles.xml
CONFLICT (modify/delete): app/src/main/java/volo/global/pingbing/StartupActivity.java deleted in origin/develop and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of app/src/main/java/volo/global/pingbing/StartupActivity.java left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Removing app/src/main/res/values-v19/styles.xml CONFLICT (modify/delete): 
app/src/main/java/volo/global/pingbing/StartupActivity.java 
deleted in origin/develop and modified in HEAD. 
Version HEAD of app/src/main/java/volo/global/pingbing/StartupActivity.java left in tree. 
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

As mentioned in "[How do I fix a merge conflict due to removal of a file in a branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1380809/6309)", you need to accept what is in the tree:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Accept changes from HEAD"
```

Comment: the issue is that the origin/develop showing empty fully....no code...but actually there is heap of code written....

Comment: @VAEntertaiment Yes, but the error message explains how to get back that code: simple git add, then commit (which will finalize the merge) then push.

Comment: hmmm isn't it risky?what if it will merge with empty code if it shows the empty code from server side?

Comment: @VAEntertaiment You can review the result before commit and push, so try it and see if the result in your local tree is what you want.

Comment: @VAEntertaiment Have yo tried to run git mergetool and just keep the file that is not empty?

Comment: ahh ok got it and there is always chance to revert back the local changes if it won`t fit my needs right?

Comment: @VAEntertaiment Exactly: those changes remains local until you push.

Comment: perfect and what about the git merge tool?did not hear about it

Comment: @VAEntertaiment, When you have conflicts, as in your case, it is a tool that shows you a base file, your changed file and the remote file. And then you edit the file in order to “merge” the conflict

Comment: @VAEntertaiment https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool for instance https://www.toofishes.net/blog/three-way-merging-git-using-vim/

Comment: got that will try all this and let you know what happened :)