# Git - how to automatically resolve "deleted by us" conflict when cherry-picking

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick, git-merge-conflict

I run the following command:

```
git cherry-pick SHA --strategy-option theirs
```

and get a conflict like this waiting for manual resolution:

```
deleted by us: SOME_FILE
```

Is there a way to make git automatically resolve such conflicts by adding files *deleted by us*?

Comment: It's not *automatic* but you can simply `git add` those files back since Git leaves the "theirs" version in the work-tree. You can do this with a script that uses `git ls-files --stage` to find files that are present in stages 1 and 3 but absent in stage 2: since 1 = base, 2 = ours, 3 = theirs, such files are precisely those "deleted by us".

Answer (score 24):

> **deleted by us** are the new files which you added in your commit (getting cherry picked). But these files are not present in the
>   current branch (the one in which you are cherry-picking into).

So in this case you have to add these files **manually** by running:

```
git add <file-path>
```

However if you think, these files will no longer be needed in the current branch after cherry picking, in that case you can do:

```
git rm <file-path>
```

Comment: Or use `git add .` to simply add all files from the `cherry-pick` (ignore our deletion in our branch)

Answer (score 13):

If you are sure you want to add all "deleted by us" files, you could do:

```
git status | sed -n 's/deleted by us://p' | xargs git add
```

or, if you want to remove all "deleted by us" files:

```
git status | sed -n 's/deleted by us://p' | xargs git rm
```

Comment: Windows command please?

Comment: To make this work with filename which include spaces : `git status | sed -n 's/\tdeleted by us:   //p' | awk '{ printf "\"%s\"\n", $0 }' | xargs git add`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't know which file would need the conflict resolution until the error pops up. So, the scenario is : I created a new file, committed it (ID1), modified it and committed it again (ID2) in source branch (cherry-pick from), and when I used the "modified" commit ID (ID2) for cherry-pick, git complained because the file never existing in the target branch (cherry-pick into).

git cherry-pick threw the following error:

```
CONFLICT (modify/delete): <SOME_FILE> deleted in HEAD and modified in <SHA>... Update the CSV file content. Version <SHA>... Update the CSV file content of <SOME_FILE> left in tree.
```

git status showed

```
deleted by us SOME_FILE
```

Based on inspiration from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41364780/10412648), here's a solution I tried. The mergetool (eg: vimdiff3 used here) allows us to choose a conflict resolution: Use (m)odified or (d)eleted file, or (a)bort. Please note, merge tool creates *.orig file which needs cleaning as necessary.

```
sha=<enter SHA>
conflict_resolution='m'
file_path=<enter file path in the repo>

if ! git cherry-pick $sha --strategy-option theirs
then
        echo "Auto Merge failed. Attempting to use merge tool."
        yes $conflict_resolution | git mergetool --tool=vimdiff3 -- $file_path
        git clean -f *.orig
        git commit -m "From Jenkins Job: ${JOB_NAME}  Build: ${BUILD_NUMBER}"
        echo "Merge successful using merge tool"
else
        echo "Auto Merge successful."
fi
```

PS: Along with cherry-pick, I guess the solution can also be applied for a typical merge scenario.