# How to force remote in a GIT modify/delete conflict?

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

When merging my branch, there are lots of those Modify/Delete conflicts. Too many to resolve manually.

When I do the

```
yes d | git mergetool
```

as described here: [How do I fix a merge conflict due to removal of a file in a branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380670/how-do-i-fix-a-merge-conflict-due-to-removal-of-a-file-in-a-branch), I can delete every file.

But I want to use whatever {remote} has, not just blindly delete.
So if {remote} deleted the file, delete it. But if {local} deleted it and {remote} modified it, restore it.

How do I do this?

Comment: There's no trivial off-the-shelf solution for this that I know of (doesn't mean there isn't one), but it's easy to code up using `git status` or `git ls-files --stage`. You will have to write some shell script. Note that other than for renamed files (which are problematic) you're just looking for files that exist at stages 1 and 3 with different hash IDs, and do not exist at stage 2. Collect the names of such files and use `git checkout` or `git restore` to extract the `--theirs` version, then `git add` the result.

Comment: This here did the trick for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46591569/7925800

Comment: That method does *more* than you asked for, so be very sure that the merge result you got is what you really wanted.